# Discrepancy between Python googlemaps library and Google Places API call with Postman

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

When I retrieve JSON code from Google Places API with Postman with this GET call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=movie_theater&location=-36.8485,174.763336&radius=10000&key=PutYourAPIKeyHere
```

I see that after `"types"` there is `"vicinity"`; then the brackets close and open again for the next business:

[image]

But if I use the official [Google Maps Python library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) in order to retrieve the same call:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='PutYourAPIKeyHere')
search_loction = gmaps.places("nearby",location='-36.8485, 174.763336', type="movie_theater")
print (search_loction)
```

I see that after `"types"` there is no `"vicinity"` and brackets are closing like it was the last element for that business?

[image]

In the Postman API call I'm passing `nearbysearch` while with Python I'm passing `nearby`.

So is `nearbysearch` the same as `nearby`?

If not what is the nearbysearch for googlemaps library?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, I will post the answer for those who struggles like me:

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='PutYourAPIKeyHere')

search_loction = gmaps.places_nearby(location='-36.8485, 174.763336', type="movie_theater",radius="10000")
#print (search_loction)
Total_Places_Found = 0


if search_loction['status'] == 'OK':
    Total_Places_Found += len(search_loction['results'])

    for element in search_loction['results']:
        Place_ID = element['place_id']
        ID = element['id']
        Name = element['name']
        Latitude = element['geometry']['location']['lat']
        Longitude = element['geometry']['location']['lng']
        Rating = element['rating']
        Types = element['types']
        vicinity = element['vicinity']
        print (vicinity)
```